# Chainlink Node - encode_tx error incorrect length

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I'm developing an external adapter and it's not working when I make a request to my local chainlink node. I have this error in the `encode_tx` step.

This is the error: `ETHABIEncode: while converting argument 'data' from <nil> to bytes32: incorrect length: expected 32, got 32: bad input for task: bad input for task`

This is the jobSpec:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "eth-lottery-job-test4"
contractAddress = "0x1Cc100f9c198d9CD3410263D4Df7FA7C5C30E34F"
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type="ethabidecodelog"
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type="bridge" name="eth-lottery-test" requestData="{\\"id\\":$(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": {\\"username\\":$(decode_cbor.username), \\"password\\":$(decode_cbor.password), \\"winner_ticket\\":$(decode_cbor.winner_ticket), \\"tickets\\":$(decode_cbor.tickets)}}"]
    parse        [type="jsonparse" path="data,winners" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_data  [type="ethabiencode" abi="(uint256[] winners)" data="{ \\"winners\\": $(parse) }"]
    encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes32 data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type="ethtx" to="0x1Cc100f9c198d9CD3410263D4Df7FA7C5C30E34F" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_data -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

I think the problem is in the encode_data task in `abi=(uint256[] winners)` . Is this the correct abi for an array of uint256?

The output of the `parse` task is `[6,14,25]` and the output of the `encode_data` task is: `0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019`

I also believe that the encode task result is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by changing the `bytes32` parameter type of `data` in the `encode_tx` task.

Comment: Awesome! What did you change it to?

Comment: I change it to `bytes` and the job works pretty well.But now I have issues to store that array in the contract with the `fulfillment` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your job spec Toml file. In this I have used `fulfillOracleRequest2()` instead of `fulfilloraclRequest()`, this function provide bytes datatype to data variable so that it won't encounter length error.

```
encode_tx    [type="ethabiencode"
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_data)}"
                 ]
```